# How to check for two jsf values p:selectOneMenu and p:calendar?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need user to be able enter a value in any one of the two controls not the other and must enter value in atleast one.How can I handle this ?

**Control 1**

```
<p:calendar id="value1" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selected.value1}" required="???" />
```

**Control 2**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="value2" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selected.value2}" required="???" />
```

Is there any check like **`required=#{ value1 != value2}`**

Comment: Where did you learn that usage of `param`? I don't see how that could possibly work. `param` is "A Map (name and value) of HTTP request parameters, containing only the first value for each name" ([ref](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.ca/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html)).

Comment: And when you say you "want to check is there some value in selectOneMenu", do you mean you want to check the currently _selected_ value, or just whether the menu _contains_ the value?

Comment: Just to check if it contain the value. I wolud like to have something like this required=#{ value1 != value2}

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your question, but I think you will need to use AJAX for this. You should be able to modify the [Primefaces Dropdown example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml) to your situation.

Comment: When user enter value in one control why do n't you disable other ?

Comment: Great idea, but I dont know how to do that with selectOneMenu and calednar, with buttons it is easy.